# Decoding mp3 file

Tags: c#, naudio, bitarray

Can any one tell me that how to decode mp3 file.
I want to decode mp3 file likewise any media player but my work is to decode and read its specific characteristics.
**Can I use NAudio for this purpose?**
Now what I need is RAWDATA of the mp3 file.

Comment: Why can't you? What errors do you get?

Comment: You should read the errormessage before asking questions i guess...

Comment: I actually don't know how to do it programmatically.

Comment: i have displayed all the bits
BitArray bits = new BitArray(FrameByteArray);
foreach (bool b in bits)
            {
                
                    if (b == true)
                    {
                        Console.Write(" 1");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write(" 0");
                    }
            }

now how i can access any bit by using index number e.g if i want to access 38th bit, how to do it???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this method 
bits[index]
you can access

e.g

```
BitArray bits = new BitArray(FrameByteArray);
Console.Write(bits[59]);
```

Answer (score 0):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.get.aspx

BitArray.Get Method: Gets the value of the bit at a specific position in the BitArray.

Comment: How i can access specific bit e.g 49th bit of the array

Comment: 'bits.Get(49)' I'd say. Or technically 48 if it's the 49th I suppose. But the answers above are also correct, BitArray also defines an indexer so bits[48] will also work. I don't really see what the problem is to be honest...

Answer (score 0):

```
bool value = bits[149];
```

Remember that the index is zero-based.

[MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.item.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The `BitArray` class definitely defines an indexer, so you shouldn't have any problem getting the value using `bits[149]`. That value will be a `bool` rather than an `int` though, so you have to check it against `true`/`false` rather than `1`/`0`.

Comment: i have displayed all the bits
BitArray bits = new BitArray(FrameByteArray);
foreach (bool b in bits)
            {
                
                    if (b == true)
                    {
                        Console.Write(" 1");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write(" 0");
                    }
            }

now how i can access any bit by using index number e.g if i want to access 38th bit, how to do it???

Comment: @YasirAwan - The example is above. You can use the indexer that exists on the `BitArray` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.item.aspx). Just remember that it uses a zero based index so to get ther 38th bit, you would use `bits[37]`.